# Facing issue while doing ADC conversion

Tags: adc, conversion

[image]I am new to the PIC programming, and in below program trying to blink LED for specific range of resistance. But when i have debug , i found it out that while loop established to wait till conversion happens in ADC_Read() is not getting completed.Please Help. attached circuit diagram too with this thread.

```
#include<pic.h>
#include<htc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 2000000

void delay(int cnt)
{
    while(cnt--);
}

void ADC_Init()
{
 ADCON0=0X81;
 ADCON1=0XCE; 
}    

int ADC_Read(unsigned int ch)
{
    ADCON0=0X81;
    ADCON1=0XCE;
    int result;

    delay(50);

    ADON=1;
    while(ADON==1);
    result=ADRESH;
    result=result<<8;
    result=result|ADRESL;
    return(result);

}

int main()
{
    unsigned int adcValue;
    TRISA=0X01;
    PORTB=0X00;
    TRISB0=0X00;

    ADC_Init();
    while(1)
    {
        adcValue=ADC_Read(0);
        if(adcValue>=300 && adcValue<=500)
        {
            RB0=1;
        }
        else
        {
            RB0=0;
        }
    }
  return 0;  
}
```

[image]

Comment: To me you should be using the GO/!DONE bit in the while loop, not the ADON bit.  BTW, a 4.7K ohm resistor on a (assuming 5V) drive level will make the LED current pretty small, unless the LED is a high efficiency type.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. But i am getting undefined  identifier error if i use GODONE

Comment: hi isdi,worked with GO_nDONE. If you come to know if data sheet dont have this parameter , then from where this worked . Please do let me know.

Comment: You'll have to check the library definition, or just use a register mask operation to check the bit if you don't feel like looking for it.  The register definition labels in the XC compilers are not 100% the same as the datasheet defs.

Comment: The library defs are in "pic16f876a.h" (or whatever processor you're using), usually found under the particular version of xc compiler in the include directory.

Comment: isdi you are the savior. Appreciate the kind help

Comment: I've reformatted the above as the answer for this topic.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the GO/!DONE bit (GO_nDONE) in the while loop, not the ADON bit.

The library defs are in "pic16f876a.h" (or whatever processor you're using), usually found under the particular version of xc compiler in the include directory.

BTW, a 4.7K ohm resistor on a (assuming 5V) drive level will make the LED current pretty small, unless the LED is a high efficiency type it will be dim.